# How to determine the ad network for a particular mobile app?

Tags: ads

I've been watching this app and their ad on the lock screen, I'd like to know which ad network they're using, is there a way to find this out?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**AdMob** *brings together best-in-class technology in a single platform, so you can gain insights about your users, drive more in-app purchases, and maximize your ad revenue. No longer will you have to rely on a combination of tools or use precious development resources to build your own solution.*

please check the official tutorial by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).

and check different examples by Googleads in [GitHub](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/releases/tag/2.8) .